# FFmpeg Script to recursively convert DTS audio to AC3

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, ffmpeg

I have videos with dts audio I can convert to ac3 separately, but I need to batch convert a bunch, but can't figure out how.

This is my working ffmpeg for separate files:

```
for f in *.mkv; 
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="AC3 5.1" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-hel/temp/${f%.mkv}".mkv;
done
```

All videos are located in separate folders under my main ”media” folder. Some folders with spaces in them.
In the working script the file gets processed to separate temp dir.

I need help with:

- For ffmpeg to convert all mkvs recursively.
- for ffmmpeg to process the separate converted mkvs to my temp dir.

Also next step if anyone has ideas:

- Use the processed videos in temp dir to replace original unconverted files.

Comment: What do you mean by "*process*" the separate converted mkvs in your temp dir? Do you just want to save them to a temp dir so you can then overwrite the original? Or is there some more processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it recursive, you can either use `find` or activate the `globstar` bash option:

1. `find -exec`:

   ```
   find . -name '*.mkv' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="AC3 5.1" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k /srv/dev-disk-by-label-hel/temp/{} \;
   ```

   The `{}` inside the `-exec` will be converted to the current file name. I didn't bother with your `${f%.mkv}".mkv;` since that is identical to the input file name, you're removing a `.mkv` and then adding it, so I assumed that was a mistake.
2. `globstar`. This option lets `**` recurse into 0 or more subdirectories.

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   for f in **/*.mkv; 
   do 
       fname="${f##*/}"
       ffmpeg -i "$f" -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="AC3 5.1" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-hel/temp/"$fname";
   done
   ```

   This is the one you can most easily make copy the files back to the original. **As long as you don't mind overwriting the originals**, you can do:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   for f in **/*.mkv; 
   do 
       fname="${f##*/}"
       ffmpeg -i "$f" -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="AC3 5.1" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-hel/temp/$fname" &&
       mv "/srv/dev-disk-by-label-hel/temp/$fname" "$f"
   done
   ```

Comment: This is great, i am using youre globstar with the mv command. I just changed the line: ´for f in *.mkv;´  To: ´for f in **/*.mkv;´ Otherwise no file would be found. Edit: there should be a star before my .mkv , but it doent show for some reason

Comment: @Set d'oh! I'm an idiot, I completely forgot to add it when writing the answer, I just copied the glob from yours. Thanks for spotting it! Note that you want `**/*.mkv`, not `**/.mkv`, but I guess you already figured that out.